# How to insert text of <figcaption> as value of attribute of <a> tag using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I started learning jQuery and wanted to make some work on the following structure.

```html
<figure class="blog_image_wrap" style="text-align: center">
<a href="https://ahmcho.com/storage/app/uploads/public/5a6/5d4/672/5a65d467293cd550396758.jpg"><img  class="text-center" src="https://ahmcho.com/storage/app/uploads/public/5a6/5d4/672/5a65d467293cd550396758.jpg" style="width:50%;"></a>
<figcaption class="blog_image_wrap">
    Gary Oldman
</figcaption>
</figure>
```

There are multiple `<figure>` tags in one page and I want to extract the text of corresponding `<figcaption>` and pass it as a value of `data-caption` attribute for `<a>` tag.  For all '' elements inside '' elements.

I have the following code but it passes all text values of `<figcaption>` texts as one for all `<a>`  elements :

```
$(document).ready(function() 
 {
     $('figure').each(function() 
     {
         $("figure>a").attr('data-caption', $("figure").find('figcaption').text()); 
     });
     $("figure>a").attr("data-fancybox" , "test");
});
```

I would appreciate if someone would point me what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `this` to target the current element in each iteration of `each()`. Then find the specific `a` from that element to set the attribute. Try the following way:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('figure').each(function() {
    $(this).find('a').attr('data-caption', $(this).find('figcaption').text());
    $(this).find('a').attr("data-fancybox" , "test");
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure class="blog_image_wrap" style="text-align: center">
<a href="https://ahmcho.com/storage/app/uploads/public/5a6/5d4/672/5a65d467293cd550396758.jpg"><img  class="text-center" src="https://ahmcho.com/storage/app/uploads/public/5a6/5d4/672/5a65d467293cd550396758.jpg" style="width:50%;"></a>
<figcaption class="blog_image_wrap">
    Gary Oldman
</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thank you for the snippet! Wish I could upvote your answer, unfortunately I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

Since you iterating through figure, you need to find the `a` and `figcaption` on current iteration. To find the current figure object you can use `$(this)`. So, to find the `a` and `figcatption` you can have following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
 {
     $('figure').each(function() 
     {
         $(this).find("a").attr('data-caption', $(this).find('figcaption').text()); 
     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer!